# Stuck with the UNET Stack .nam Trace File

Tags: unetstack

I am trying to write my own python script to compute the statistics calculated by UNET Stack. I have generated the.nam trace file for the ALOHA sample file and I am writing my script to do the following:

compute received packets
compute enqueued packets (sent)
compute dequeued packets (sent)
compute dropped packets

using what is written in the handbook (https://unetstack.net/handbook/unet-handbook_discrete_event_simulation.html), my script computes received packets by detecting if the line in the trace starts with 'r' and if it does, I increment my counter. Similarly, if a line starts with 'd', I increment the dropped packet count & similarly for enqueued & dequeued packets as well.

My statistics are not matching with the values shown by UNET Stack for each simulation.

I do not understand where the error lies and I would be very glad if anyone could help me out.

I expect to get a similar output to the results shown when I run the ALOHA file in UnetSim but I receive a different result using the logic stated above. I have attached the .nam file incase anyone wants to check it out.

.nam file -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/15LilwmV2uTOvDy76Y1ZRG2JR1qPa_0Cs/view?usp=sharing

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ioul.png)
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwWRo.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the stats brings up two things:

1. You seem to be accounting for receiving 3x the number of frames transmitted, i.e., maybe ignoring the destination address and so triple-counting?
2. The number of transmissions shown in the expected results is smaller than the number of transmissions you see; maybe the time over which the expected results were computed is shorter from the time over which the nam file is logged? I believe the tracer stats use a warm-up period during which transmissions are ignored for stats (but they'll be logged).

Comment: 1) I understand. So I need to modify the code to ensure that I do not double count? Will adding a check for destination address & packet ID be the correct way? Because after doing that, I am getting 569 packets instead of the 506 mentioned. 

2) So for that, do I need to work simultaneously with the log file? How do I account for this warm-up period in my own calculations?

Comment: Yes, filter on destination address. Also ignore the packets that were transmitted during the warm-up period (settable in Tracer, but defaults to 15 mins iirc).

Comment: I understand sir. After making the necessary changes, I have arrived at the following stats for 2 simulations: 
[sim1 stats by unet stack](https://imgur.com/a/tDe7kys)
[my stats for sim1](https://imgur.com/0odf3NB)
[my stats for sim2](https://imgur.com/oRSu2zD)
[sim2 stats by unet stack](https://imgur.com/DaLhWQK)

There is still an error in the dropped packet count which gets more enhanced as the number of packets increase. I was wondering if it's because we are considering the dropped packets which were created before the warm-up time?

Comment: The effect of warm-up should be smaller when you increase the duration of the simulation.